# передача вектора в функцию

Tags: c++, vector

Функция требует в качестве параметра указатель на массив `const int*`. Требуется передать вектор `v<int>`.

Эквивалентны ли следующие передачи:
`&v[0]` и `v.begin()` ?

Comment: Вопрос в том, _почему_ у вас такая странная функция. Переделайте её, делов-то.

Comment: @VladD функция может требовать указатель, т.к. написана на `c` например. Или уже имеется рабочий интерфейс. А `std::vector` довольно легко можно подружить с нативным указателем там где надо.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну так тогда не надо использовать это функцию. Надо переписать её в шаблонный вариант, чтобы принимала два итератора. Тогда и проблем с <s>натягиванием совы</s> конвертацией типов данных не будет.

Comment: @VladD Вы не поняли, видимо. Допустим есть библиотека (исключительно в бинарном виде), и одна из функций в этой библиотеке принимает `const int*`. Вы не можете переписать эту функцию, или что-либо вообще в этой библиотеке.

Comment: @alexolut: Такое бывает, да. Но в нормальных случаях исходники есть, и такое не нужно. Вангую, что и в данном случае исходники есть.

Comment: @VladD то что Вы называете "нормальными" случаями - это скорее "идеальные" случаи. Ну или варианты каких-либо open-source. Потому что, иначе, библиотеку предоставляют именно в варианте `dll/so/lib` + `*.h`. Разумеется без самих исходников.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v.begin()` возвращает итератор, это не `const int*`.
`&*v.begin()`, `&v[0]` и `v.data()` - эквивалентны.

Использование `v.data()` предпочтительнее, т.к. оно лучше передает намерение.

Comment: Кроме намерения, это ещё и единственная функция(из предложенных), которая может быть выполнена на пустом векторе

Comment: Тип итератора `implementation-defined`, так что формально он может быть и обычным указателем.

Comment: @ixSci любопытно, что для `std::basic_string` `&v[0]` можно вызывать и на пустом контейнере. Главное, не писать туда.

Comment: @alexolut, это больше похоже на недосмотр в стандарте, к тому же у меня вызывает вопрос тот факт, что в описании `begin()` говорится, что возвращает итератор на первый элемент, но первого элемента в пустой строке нет. Мне кажется, хотя это явно и не написано, подобное поведение не разрешено, хотя и будет работать почти везде, за счёт SSO.

Comment: @ixSci удивительно быстро кто-то задал подходящий вопрос. Вот мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508522/176217) со сноской на Стандарт в том числе.

Comment: @alexolut, хех, я ведь ту же строчку стандарта прочитал, и в упор не увидел знака `<` и не прочитал окончание предложения.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не эквивалентны, т.к. `v.begin()` возвращает итератор (т.е. `std::vector<int>::iterator`) на первый элемент `vector<int>`, а `&v[0]` указатель на адрес в памяти, где расположен элемент из vector'а (т.е. `int*`).

Соответственно, интерфейс работы с такими типами различен, но, опять же, никто не запрещает разыменовать итератор (но предварительно следует проверить не указывает ли итератор на на `v.end()`), а затем взять адрес полученного элемента.

А так как `vector` эмулирует работу стандартного массива C (например, быстрый произвольный доступ к элементам), то все элементы в нем располагаются общим скопом (т.е. располагаются подряд в памяти), поэтому вам подойдет способ передачи `&v[0]`, а перемещение по элементам массива через `operator ++` примененный к параметру функции, например.

---

Но в таком случае вам стоит заранее обдумать каким именно образом вы будете учитывать границы массива:

1. Передавать размер массива вторым параметром
2. Использовать какой-нибудь барьерный элемент, который должен находиться в конце вашего массива и никогда не должен присутствовать в вашем массиве кроме как барьерный, непосредственно, а также с которым необходимо будет сравнивать значение текущего элемента на каждом шаге для определения конца массива

---

Пример реализации посредством 1-го пункта:

```
#include <vector>

void func(const int* parm, const int elemsCount)
{
    for (int itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < elemsCount; ++itemNumber, ++parm)
    {
        // ToDo: дейтсвия с *parm
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    func(&v[0], v.size());
}
```