# Хранится ли в конце string терминальный символ?

Tags: c++

Хранится ли в конце строк типа `string` терминальный символ?

Comment: Но: этот же символ может быть и в _середине_ `std::string`.

Answer (score 20):

### Да.

<sub>Или, как минимум, для него зарезервировано место и подделано его значение. Это было бы нерационально, но не запрещено и потому может иметь место.</sub>

**С C++11** это гарантируется, потому что метод `c_str` у `std::string` должен **(а)** работать за **константное время** и **(б)** возвращать указатель непосредственно на внутренний буфер объекта-строки.

> This array includes the same sequence of characters that make up the value of the string object plus an additional terminating null-character ('\0') at the end.
>
> — [cplusplus.com, `std::string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Хотя когда работа идёт с самим `std::string` (а не его C-совместимым кусочком), **терминальный символ может и не играть своей роли**, и можно считать, что он не существует.

Терминальным он является только для алгоритмов, которые эту строку используют.

Comment: Да уж, все течет все изменяется. Помнится лет 5 назад, тут (на ХК) мне с пеной у рта доказывали (тыкая носом в такой же дурацкий стандарт и не соглашаясь с логикой возможной реализации), что передавать в Сишные функции адрес из середины std::string небезопасно, поскольку стандарт не гарантирует нуля в конце...

Comment: @avp, Стандарт не дурацкий. Просто: а) он не идеален; б) развивается. Но лучше следовать букве закона (Стандарта), а не полагаться на имплементацию, которая может измениться при переходе на другую систему в самых неожиданных, на первый взгляд, местах.

Comment: @alexolut, или делать имплементации, меняющие стандарты :-).

Comment: @avp: передавать в сишные функции адрес из середины std::string всё ещё небезопасно: в середине std::string может быть \0, в отличие от сишной строки.

Comment: @VladD ну... у вас другое "безопасно". Это не приведёт к UB из-за вылезания за границы строки, как если бы стандарт не гарантировал там завершающего нуля. Это *немножко неожиданно*, да, но чтобы *опасно* -- не сказал бы.

Comment: @D-side: Ну да, а имел в виду опасно в смысле «молча, без предупреждения делает не то, что вы имели в виду».

Comment: @VladD, конечно, недопонимание с нулями в строке вполне возможно. Невозможность хранения нулей в сишных строках иногда можно преодолеть довольно неочевидным способом. Например, если текстовый редактор хранит файл по строкам, то очевидно, что в них нет `\n`-ов. И тогда можно заменять нули на них, а при выводе в файл делать обратную замену (естественно, при выводе на экран тоже нужна отдельная проверка для печати, скажем, `C-@`)

Comment: @avp: А что, красивая идея! Возьму на вооружение.

Answer (score 12):

Стандарт [гарантирует](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.access#2), что если у `std::string` запросить последний символ тем или иным способом (например через `operator[]` с аргументом `size()`), то вернется символ, аналогичный сконструированному вызовом `char()`, т.е. `0`. Так что можно сказать, что `0` существует в конце строки.

---

При этом в Стандарте всё же присутствует некоторая несогласованность. 
Например, описание конструктора, который вызывается конструктором по умолчанию, [гласит](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.classes#string.cons-1), что:

> функция-член `data()` после инициализации объекта возвращает не-нулевой
>   указатель, по которому **может** содержаться 0.

Т.е. может, но не обязан. При этом для значения, полученного через `data()` справедливо [равенство](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.ops#string.accessors-1):

> `p + i == &operator[](i)`, для всех i в диапазоне [0, size()]

А учитывая работу `operator[]`, о чем сказано в самом начале моего ответа, получается, что `0` всё же не просто может, а **обязан** существовать в памяти.