# string и завершающий ноль

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с задачей архивирования файлов методом Хаффмана, работаю в бинарном режиме и иногда в файлах встречается символ завершающего нуля, который приводит к проблемам с использованием string.

**Вопрос: можно ли как-то сделать чтобы string считал его просто символом? Если да, то как?** А то очень не охота страдать с Cишными массивами char'ов

Comment: А `std::string` и считает его просто символом. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null

Comment: Плюсую. Я даже об этом писал: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508524/181100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Передавайте длину массива байт в конструктор строки:

```
const char lit[] = "abc\0def";
std::string s(lit, sizeof(lit) - 1);
// или
std::string s(lit, lit + sizeof(lit) - 1);
// но не
// std::string s(lit);
```

Впрочем строка - это не самый подходящий тип для массива байт, предпочтительнее использовать `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` или [`gsl::span<std::uint8_t>`](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#a-namess-viewsagslview-views).

Comment: ваш вариант какой-то странный, если учесть что я считываю данные из файла, но за vector<uint8_t> спасибо, думаю это отличный выбор

Comment: @Xambey, если вы подбираете контейнер для массива работы с битами то я бы обратил внимание на std bitset, он имеет все операции для манипуляции с битами и их преобразованием (для этого он и создовался), в том числе и метод `to_string` для преобразования его в строку.

Comment: еще раз спасибо, вопрос закрыт