# Как работает c_str() в c++?

Tags: c++, массивы

Меня интересует как выглядит массив на который стоит указатель.

Я так понимаю что функция берет строку например string str = "12345" и превращает в массив чаров {'1' ,'2' ,'3' ,'4' ,'5' , \0 } а потом возвращает указатель на этот массив

Или так {"12345"} ?

И еще такой момент , если возвращает указатель то почему работает вот это :

```
cout << str.c_str() <<endl;
```

Comment: "12345" и есть массив чаров {'1' ,'2' ,'3' ,'4' ,'5' , \0 }

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Хранится ли в конце string терминальный символ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/508516/176217).

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, `string::c_str` возвращает указатель на область памяти, где хранит саму строку. То есть, при возвращении не создает никаких дополнительных массивов, ничто никуда не преобразовывает и не копирует.

Насчет `cout << str.c_str() <<endl;`: `cout` отлично выводит на экран указатели типа `char *` или `const char *` как строки. Вас же не смутит запись `cout << "12345" << endl;`