# Вывод пустой строки в C++

Tags: c++, строки

Почему в коде на С++

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::string E;
    E[0] = 'a';
    std::cout << E[0];
    std::cout << E;
}
```

вывод строки E пустой, хотя строка не должна быть пустой после присвоения значения первому элементу строки? И где найти информацию по этому поводу?

Comment: Строка пуста, и у нее *НЕТ* первого элемента. По сути, это выход за пределы массива. Выведите дополнительно `E.size()` - вы увидите 0. Лучше уж писать `E='a';`...

Comment: да что же это такое. `E='a';` не скомпилится. Но три плюса вверх поставили.

Comment: @KoVadim, https://ideone.com/MCBDzW

Comment: странно, у меня такое раньше не компилировалось.... пойду поищу этот проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменение строки по индексу с помощью `[]` приводит к неопределённому поведению. Этот оператор предназначен для быстрой обработки строк. Если программист знает, что хочет.

А если не уверен, то надо использовать другую функцию `at`, которая следит за  неправильным доступом к строке и вызовет исключение.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    try {
        std::string E;
        E.at(0) = 'a';
        std::cout << E.at(0);
        std::cout << E;   }
    catch(std::exception const & ex){
        std::cerr<<"exception : " << ex.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

проверяем :

```
exception : basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

Исключение : аргумент индекса равен нулю, который больше или равен размеру строки, которая равняется нулю.

Чтобы **добавить** буквы к строке надо использовать другие функции : например оператор `+=`

```
E += 'a' ;
```

Почему у вас пустая строка - это неопределённое поведение. Зависит от реализации компилятора и случая.

Answer (score 1):

Запустим такой код:

```
string E;
cout << E.size() << endl;
```

и увидим вывод - 0. Т.е. нет никаких элементов строки вовсе, и запись *любого* элемента пустой строки есть по сути выход за границы выделенной памяти и UB.

Как именно отреагирует на ваше самовольство программа - зависит от конкретного компилятора, реализации `string`, уровня оптимизации etc etc - на то это поведение и undefined...

Можно просто присвоить `E = 'a';`, можно `E += 'a';` - словом, по-разному, но в рамках стандарта :)

Comment: я бы не был столь категоричен. Чтение элемента по размеру строки это нормально. Вот с записью уже хуже. То есть, ещё раз, `std::string s; std::cout << s[0];` - здесь все ок.

Comment: @KoVadim Если не ошибаюсь, не гарантируется, что в неинициализированной (не `string E = ""`) строке указатель вообще куда-то указывает? он может быть и нулевым, нет? В стандарте сказано только `size() is equal to 0`, а о том, куда указывает `data()` - ничего не пишут. Тогда это может быть и `nullptr`, нет? а в какой мере нормально чтение `((char*)nullptr)[0]`? (Еще раз - я говорю о теоретически возможном варианте реализации, а не о том, как обычно `string` реализован на практике.)

Comment: а какая разница, что там именно внутри.  К тому же при чтении по индексу равному размеру может просто быть отдельная ветка, которая возвращает `\0`.

Comment: @KoVadim Да, в принципе есть такое... `constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;` -  Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object to any value other than `charT()` leads to undefined behavior. Так что с замечанием *о чтении* соглашусь.

Comment: Если бы не это в стандарте - то разница может быть, и очень большая. "Может быть" и "стандарт гарантирует" - все же две большие разницы...

Comment: я знаю, что такое UB, я знаю, какие могут  быть последствия. Остальные ошибки в "ответе" исправите?

Comment: @KoVadim по наличию терминального нуля в `std::string` есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/508516/176217)

Answer (score 1):

У вас, как уже выше отметили, отсутствует инициализация строки.
Поэтому на момент вызова она пуста. Цитирую сайт https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/2.16.php.
Для инициализации строк можно использовать различные способы:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::string s1;                 //пустая строка
    std::string s2 = "hello";        //hello
    std::string s3("welcome");       //welcome
    std::string s4(5, 'h');     //hhhhh
    std::string s5 = s2;             //hello
     
    std::cout << s1 << "\n";
    std::cout << s2 << "\n";
    std::cout << s3 << "\n";
    std::cout << s4 << "\n";
    std::cout << s5 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: у автора вопроса есть инициализация строки. Тем более Вы сами приводите такую инициализацию в своем примере.

Comment: @KoVadim я все таки имел ввиду инициализацию присвоением значения. У автора выше это нельзя назвать инициализацией в полной мере, а лишь объявлением.

Comment: почему? и у него определение, а не объявление.